# Remove duplicate rows using linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am not the greatest with linq but is the language of choice. I'm trying to write the query using sql like.  Standard scenerio I have an invoice and that invoice had invoice details. When joining the tables together of course the invoices that have mulitple details are going to repeat.  In standard sql I could use distinct or group by.  I've tried to follow that with linq but getting errors or it is just not filtering them out.

Here is my query

```
var result = (from invoice in invoices
      join invoiceItem in invItems on invoice.Id equals invoiceItem.InvoiceId
      orderby invoice.InvoiceNo
      select new InvoiceReceiveShipmentVM
      {
          dtInvoiced = invoice.dtInvoiced,
          InvoiceNumber = invoice.InvoiceNo,
          InvoiceType = invoice.InvoiceType,
          InvoiceStatus = invoice.InvoiceStatus,
          Lines = invoiceItem.Line,
          Total = invoice.Total,
          Carrier = invoice.Carrier,
      });
return result.Distinct();
```

I've also tried :

```
         var myList = result.GroupBy(x => x.InvoiceNumber)
                            .Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
        return myList.Skip(fetch.Skip).Take(fetch.Take).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: You should probably describe what you are hoping to filter out. e.g. maybe show the result you expect to get, and what this query is (incorrectly?) giving you.

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct, please override Equals and GetHashCode in InvoiceReceiveShipmentVM

```
public class InvoiceReceiveShipmentVM
{
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is InvoiceReceiveShipmentVM == false) return false;

        var invoice = (InvoiceReceiveShipmentVM)obj;
        return invoice.InvoiceNumber == InvoiceNumber
            && invoice.InvoiceType == InvoiceType
            && invoice.InvoiceStatus == InvoiceStatus
            && invoice.Lines == Lines
            && invoice.Total == Total
            && invoice.Carrier == Carrier;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return InvoiceNumber.GetHashCode()
            ^ InvoiceType.GetHashCode()
            ^ InvoiceStatus.GetHashCode()
            ^ Lines.GetHashCode()
            ^ Total.GetHashCode()
            ^ Carrier.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```